# How do I change a UIButton label text when a menu slides up or down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UITableView object inside a UIView object such that when a button is pressed, the UIView slides up from the bottom of the screen. In its initial state when the UIView is at the bottom of the screen, the button says "Slide Up", but when I tap on the button, it will slide up.

I would like the UIBUtton label to change to "Slide Down" when the UIView is up, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Attached is some pictures.

[image] [image]

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL containerIsOpen;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.containerIsOpen = NO;
}

- (IBAction)tapButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.containerIsOpen)
    {
        [self replaceConstraintOnView:self.markersView withConstant:0];
    }
    else
    {
        [self replaceConstraintOnView:self.markersView withConstant:-200.0];
    }

    [self animateConstraints];
    self.containerIsOpen = !self.containerIsOpen;
}

- (void)replaceConstraintOnView:(UIView *)view withConstant:(float)constant
{
    [self.view.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if ( (constraint.firstItem == view) && (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTop) )
        {
            constraint.constant = constant;
        }
    }];
}

- (void)animateConstraints
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can connect an IBOutlet to a constraint. Then you can change the constraint's constant through the outlet rather than having to enumerate through the view's constraints like you're doing in your replaceConstraintOnView method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setTitle:forState:` method of `UIButton`.

It allows to specify the `title` of the button for a specific state, such as `UIControlStateNormal` or `UIControlStateHighlighted`

Modify `tapButton:` like so:

```
- (IBAction)tapButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (self.containerIsOpen)
    {
        [self replaceConstraintOnView:self.markersView withConstant:0];
        [sender setTitle:@"Slide down" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self replaceConstraintOnView:self.markersView withConstant:-200.0];
        [sender @"Slide up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [self animateConstraints];
    self.containerIsOpen = !self.containerIsOpen;
}
```